# Помогите с mod_rewrite

Tags: mod_rewrite, php

Ребят, есть вот такая задача по mod_rewrite:
Есть субдомен `search.site.ru`
Есть еще один субдомен `search.example.ru`
Как мне перенаправить пользователя с `search.site.ru` на `search.example.ru` с теме же параметрами и URI, но пользователь думал что он сидит на `search.site.ru` и видел это в адресной строке?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно в настройка виртул хоста Apache в ServerAlias указать второй домен, тогда сайт будет открываться по обоим адресам без перенаправлений.

Например:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName search.site.ru
  ServerAlias search.example.ru
  ...
</VirtualHost>
```

А если эти домены находятся на разных серверах тогда можно через ProxyPass проксировать запросы на второй домен